# Building a podium with 1x1 cubes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose Lisa has a bunch of 1 x 1 x 1 inches cubes. She is building a podium. The top layer is always 2 x 3 inches and the layer below has cubes sticking out 0.5 inches on each of the 4 sides (this is true for every layer).

How can I make a summation formula to calculate the amount of cubes needed for layer n?

I know that there will always be a need for 6 cubes since the top is 2 x 3. Then i assume that the layer below will need at least the same amount of cubes as the layer above.

My first attempt to solution was to create a new layer under with the same amount of cubes as the above layer and then moving each cube out 0.5 inches to pass that requirement. I realise that I will need to add 4 cubes because 6 won't be able to cover each side. When I move those it creates a new space in the middle which is 0.5 x the amount of cubes i moved/added. So my attempted formula would be previous_layer + (previous_layer + extra added) * 0.5

But i'm not quite sure if this is right or not.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Start by figuring out how the dimensions of each layer: that tells you how many cubes will be used in each layer. If the top layer is layer $1$, the next one down is layer $2$, and so on, what are the dimensions of layer $2$? Of layer $3$? Of layer $n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re making the calculation of the number of cubes in each layer much too hard. Layer $1$, the top layer, is $2\times 3$. Layer $2$, the next layer extends half an inch further in each direction, so it must be altogether an inch wider and an inch deeper, i.e., $3\times 4$. The same reasoning shows that Layer $3$ must be $4\times 5$, and so on. We can now write down a general formula: Layer $n$ must be $(n+1)\times(n+2)$, and of course that means that it uses $(n+1)(n+2)$ cubes. A whole podium with $n$ layers will therefore $\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)(k+2)$ cubes. How you get a closed form for that will depend on what you already know; one possibility is to multiply out $(k+1)(k+2)$ and sum the terms separately, if you happen to know the formulas for the sum of consecutive squares.

Comment: Thanks! It all makes much more sense now haha. I was clearly overthinking the problem a lot.

Comment: @kingalex01: You’re welcome!

Comment: That looks like more a pyramide to me than a podium. For a podium another $3\times 2$ platform should be added and then we extend by $1$, and so on.

Comment: @zwim: I agree that it’s not a typical podium, but it’s what the problem specified.

Comment: I didn't include in the specification but the results should be like a staircase from each side pretty much.

Comment: @kingalex01: You didn’t have to: the statement that each layer extends half an inch beyond the previous layer on all four sides implies it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to go with my original idea of a podium rather than a pyramid, still with each supporting layer having the same $\pm \frac 12$ extension compared to above level.

[image]
[image]

If we call $L(n),l(n)$ the dimensions of the rectangle of layer $n$ we have:

$\begin{cases}
L(1)=3 & L(n+1)=L(n)+4 & \text{adding 3 + two margins of 1/2}\\ 
l(1)=2 & l(n+1)=l(n)+1 & \text{adding two margins of 1/2}
\end{cases}$

We solve the arithmetic progressions (with $(n-1)$ because first layer is $1$ not $0$)

We get $\begin{cases} L(n)=4(n-1)+3=4n-1\\ l(n)=1(n-1)+2=n+1\end{cases}$

The rectangle area is $A(n)=L(n)\times l(n)=(4n-1)(n+1)=4n^2+3n-1$

The total number of cubes is $$S(n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n A(k)=4\sum\limits_{k=1}^n n^2+3\sum\limits_{k=1}^n n-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 1\\=4\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\right)+3\left(\frac{n(n+1)}2\right)-n\\=\frac 16 n(8n^2+21n+7)$$